# How would you separate 100-1000 NSDates by week?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have an array of `PostSummary`s which are already organized in order from oldest to newest. I want to group each of these dates by week so I can have an array of arrays, each containing the dates for a specific week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to loop over your array and create new arrays for each week that you find contains one of your dates.  You can get the week number and year from an NSDate relatively easily, so this should be a very simple for loop.

pseudo-code

```
for(date in dates)
{
    int week = (week of date);
    int year = (year of date);
    array = dictionary objectForKey:(some id with year and week);
    if(!array)
    {
        create array;
        add array to dictionary;
    }
    array addObject:date;
}
```